# Stack around variable was corrupted

Tags: c++, c, openssl, aes, stack-corruption

I have the following program in which I encrypt and decrypt a given text using AES_CBC with a key length of 256 bits. I would like to know why I am getting the error in the title when `plaintext`, `ciphertext` and `checktext` are not globals and works fine when they are. Thank you!

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <openssl\aes.h>
#include <openssl\rand.h>
#include <conio.h>
#include <openssl\des.h>

#define BIG_TEST_SIZE 1024

char plaintext[BIG_TEST_SIZE];
char ciphertext[BIG_TEST_SIZE];
char checktext[BIG_TEST_SIZE];

AES_KEY key;
char rkey[32+1];

static void hexdump(FILE *f,const char *title,const unsigned char *s,int l)
{
        int n=0;

        fprintf(f,"%s",title);
        for( ; n < l ; ++n)
        {
                if((n%16) == 0)
                        fprintf(f,"\n%04x",n);
                fprintf(f," %02x",s[n]);
        }
        fprintf(f,"\n");
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    //char plaintext[BIG_TEST_SIZE];
    //char ciphertext[BIG_TEST_SIZE];
    //char checktext[BIG_TEST_SIZE];    

    char saved_iv[32+1];
        int err = 0;

        RAND_pseudo_bytes((unsigned char*)rkey, sizeof rkey);
        unsigned char iv[32+1]="01234567890123456789012345678901";

        memcpy(saved_iv, iv, sizeof saved_iv);

        strcpy((char*)plaintext,"aaa");

        const size_t encslength = ((strlen(plaintext) + AES_BLOCK_SIZE) / AES_BLOCK_SIZE) * AES_BLOCK_SIZE;
        // Straight encrypt

        AES_set_encrypt_key((unsigned char*)rkey, 256, &key);
        hexdump(stdout, "plaintext", (unsigned char*)plaintext, strlen(plaintext));

        AES_cbc_encrypt((unsigned char*)plaintext, (unsigned char*)ciphertext, encslength, &key, (unsigned char*)iv,AES_ENCRYPT);
        hexdump(stdout, "ciphertext", (unsigned char*)ciphertext, strlen(plaintext));

        // Straight decrypt

        AES_set_decrypt_key((unsigned char*)rkey, 256, &key);
        memcpy(iv, saved_iv, sizeof iv);

        AES_cbc_encrypt((unsigned char*)ciphertext, (unsigned char*)checktext, encslength, &key, (unsigned char*)iv,AES_DECRYPT);
        hexdump(stdout, "checktext", (unsigned char*)checktext, strlen(plaintext));


        getch();
}
```

Comment: Because they are allocated on the stack when they are declared in `main`. You could use a tool such as _valgrind_ to find invalid writes and reads.

Comment: The plaintext[] is an array, so the strcpy( plaintext, "aaa"); is correct.  The code actually used is treating the first (pointer size) bytes of plaintext as a pointer to where the "aaa" is to be stored.  Besides this error, there are other similar errors int the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Global and static variable initialize with zero while local variables are not.
So when you define **plaintext**, **ciphertext** and **checktext** locally use memset to initialize them with zero.
Your string should be null terminated but in your case it is not.
**ciphertext**, **checktext** is not null terminated. while **plaintext** become null terminated due to **strcpy** call.

Comment: I don't think that is correct. `strcpy`: "Copies the C string pointed by source into the array pointed by destination, including the terminating null character (and stopping at that point)." The example at  http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/strcpy/ is doing the exact same thing (line 11).

Comment: I thought there must be something with the null terminating character(I used a 3-length string as input and the output would not end until it reached the maximum limit), but I did not know why.